# Make a minimum manifest with static files of a mean-stack application

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I want to make a minimum `manifest.xml` for an Excel add-in with a `mean-stack` application.

First, I make a very small and working `manifest.xml` as follows, where `aLocalFile.html` is a file on my machine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
    xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
    <Id>eae66e72-84b6-4eed-b1b2-ba6fdbdb3ecf</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Test"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="Test"/>
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="Workbook" />
    </Capabilities>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost/aLocalFile.html" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Then, I start my application locally with `npm start`, as a result I could open a static webpage served by the application like `https://localhost:3000/customFunction/page.html` in a browser. (The content of `page.html` is just `<html><body>hello</body></html>`)

However, if I replace, in `manifest.xml`, `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost/aLocalFile.html" />` by `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/customFunction/page.html" />`, the add-in will not load properly. I tried to load it on Excel Online, it gave me an error: `Add-in Error Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator.` After clicking `Retry`, it gave me `Add-in Error This add-in may not load properly, but you can still try to start it.`. Then clicking `START` leads to open the page.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

**Edit 1:** I also tried `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/aPage" />` where `aPage` is a page via `ui-router` of the application, it worked without error. So it seems that the trouble mainly comes from serving static files.

Comment: I'd imagine this is something to do with the port number and the URI data type that source location is validated against.

Comment: @MaviDomates please see my Edit 1.